# Is serial port accessible through WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, printing, serial-port

I have a simple desktop application with the API library for printer that sends text on a printer connected via USB. Desktop application works fine.

The aim is to create a WCF service (hosted in windows service) through which I printed texts. From my debug log in WCF service I see that the data was properly sent to the printer, but printer reports failed. The code and data is exactly same in Desktop/WCF service. Unfortunately,  the API library function results is only "failed" and no exception/additional info. The most come to mind, that application type of WCF Service can not access the serial port defaultly. It is necessary to make special settings for WCF Service?

Windows 10

.NET Framework 4

Visual Studio 10

Printer: SANE SK1-21 (api UpdSdk.dll)

WCF Service hosted in a Windows Service

**UPDATE**
I tried to create a new minimalist windows service with a minimum of code - printing failed. Than I created a new Windows Form application and console app too with the same of code and printing is performed well.

Comment: Is your windows service running as the same user that your winforms app ran as?

Comment: I started service via "net start ...." from cmd with administrator. Winform apps is normaly started with normal user privileges.

Comment: use `services.msc` to find out what user the service is running as.  If it's `SYSTEM`, that user might not be able to access the device driver.  Try changing it to a normal user.

Comment: thanks for point to direction, i will try it tommorow and post result there

Answer (score 0):

I finded one solution. When i install windows service (which hosted wcf service) with

```
serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
```

than the printer works well. Thanks for 1.618 for point about user privilege.

but, running like LocalSystem is not appropriate via security reason. I probably need create special user account for this service with some? specific privileges. So i can not accept my own answer :)